# How to display Time in appropriate way ( Min:Sec)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I'm coding a media player app but the Time (for seekbar) appears incorrectly. Is there an error in calculation? How can I adjust the Time in the code?

```
private void updateSeekBar() {
    seekBar.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLength)*100));
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateSeekBar();
                realtimeLength-=1000; // declare 1 second
                textView.setText(String.format("%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(realtimeLength),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(realtimeLength) -
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(realtimeLength))));

            }

        };
        handler.postDelayed(updater,1000); // 1 second
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the seconds incorrectly. You need to multiply the minutes by 60 and then subtract it from total seconds to get the seconds in this minute.

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(realtimeLength) - 60 * TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(realtimeLength)
```

This should work.
You should use Debugger to try to debug why your output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass duration in below method & it will give you formatted result back.

long secs = mediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000;

```
public String makeShortTimeString(final Context context, long secs) {
    long hours, mins;
    hours = secs / 3600;
    secs %= 3600;
    mins = secs / 60;
    secs %= 60;

    String durationFormat = context.getResources().getString(
            hours == 0 ? R.string.durationformatshort : R.string.durationformatlong);
    return String.format(durationFormat, hours, mins, secs);
}
```

where durationformatshort = %2$d:%3$02d 
 and durationformatlong = %1$d:%2$02d:%3$02d